# Html.ActionLink() adds unwanted folder when actionName like "/controllerName/action/"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have created a Controller called ApplicationController that sends common information to all my views, every controller in my system inherits from it.

In a partial view i use Html.ActionLink():

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Title", "/MyController/MyAction")
// OUTPUT: <a href="/MyIISVirtualDirectory/Application/MyController/MyAction">Link Title</a>
```

If i click on the link i receive 404.

But if i use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Title", "MyAction", "MyController")
// OUTPUT: <a href="/MyIISVirtualDirectory/MyController/MyAction">Link Title</a>
```

Everything works fine.

Why in the first example the method outputs /Application/? How can i remove this by default?

Comment: Maybe because the ActionLink helper is expecting an action name, not a path to an action?

Comment: If you are going to pass the path, then just create the link "by hand" instead of using the ActionLink. But if you want to use ActionLink, then only pass in the action name, and optionally the controller name.

Comment: Did you look at the docs?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx  this question essentially boils down to "Why can't I do this in an unsupported way?"   if you really want or need to do it this way, implement your own ActionLinkHelper

Comment: Forty-Two: I tought that it would work as simple as CakePHP works. If a link starts with / the framework recognizes that i want to go somewhere that starts in the root of my application. Do you know how can i send the full path and it returns me the correct url?

Comment: Queti: The problem is that my application is under a VirtualDirectory, if i use a normal link it will send me to /controller/action not /myappdir/controller/action.

Comment: Just write out the html if you don't want to use the helper method. You can hardcode your link destinations in the href attribute

Comment: I would not recommend just writing out the html... what happens down the road when your linking strategy changes? you can easily modify your helper method, you cannot easily go through every link in your website by hand.

Comment: Exactly, also as i said before my application is under a Virtual Directory which could change any time. I need the helper to help me correct it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: As @Juventus18 mentions, your first example is not how `ActionLink` is meant to be used. Why do you want to use the first example when the second example works the way you want?

Comment: @DanielLiuzzi because i already have a string with "/controller/action". I would have to explode it in two and send the information as parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Razor 2.0 (ASP.NET MVC 4), you can just use a plain old link:

```
<a href="~/MyController/MyAction">Link Title</a>
```

The href will get converted to `/MyController/MyAction` if your app is hosted on `/` or to `/MyIISVirtualDirectory/MyController/MyAction` if your app is hosted on `/MyIISVirtualDirectory`.

In Razor 1.0 (ASP.NET MVC 3), the syntax is a bit more verbose:

```
<a href="@Href("~/MyController/MyAction")">Link Title</a>
```

More info [here](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/whats-new/top-features-in-web-pages-2).

Comment: If you want to use ~ to get the path, using an extension method as my answer shows would be much more DRY and SOLID

Comment: I think that's personal preference. To me, `<a href="~/MyController/MyAction">Link Title</a>` is standard. Anybody understands it immediately, as it is a built-in feature in the framework and, really, it doesn't get any simpler than that. Unless there were lots of logic involved to render the link (not likely) coding an extension method just for doing a simple `string.Format()` seems a bit overkill IMO. Also, there's a problem in your answer. See my coment there.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do what you want is this:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/MyController/MyAction")">Link Title</a>
```

however, it breaks routing logic completely. This should be used for content files (as name suggests), css, js, etc... not for controller actions. If you change default routing, above URL would probably break.

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem. My application is under a virtual folder, i need to get it automaticaly and i wonder if a helper could do that for me.

Comment: Ah, typo, sorry. It's fixed now.

Comment: Regarding the note about `Url.Content` breaking route logic, the problem also exists with `Url.Action` (i.e. if you change your routes and forget to update your views, your links will break as those parameters you pass to `Url.Actions` are mere strings.)

Comment: That's simply not true. Wherever you pass "controller" & "action" and not URL, it will be updated when you change routing table. Try it.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood you. I was thinking more about renaming your controller and/or action names, in which case nothing will be updated and links will break no matter what. Now if you change the routing, and only the routing, then yes, links will be updated to the right URL. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible calling a action method from a controller by giving the route as parameter. Here is a link with all the extensions for Html.ActionLink.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.108).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Routes are defined in global.asax, where you can define your routes according to your needs.
The /Application/ from the output is your ApplicationController.By default the controller in which you are calling the view is the controller that is searched for a action method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Simplifying: Is there anyway i can get the reverse information? For example, in CakePHP if i call Router::url("/controllerName/actionName") it would give me back the full path to that specific action inside a controller, including the application folder.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own Action Link helper:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public static class CustomHtmlHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string routePath)
        {
            //you can do any sort of logic you want here.
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}<a/>", routePath, linkText));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work the way you intend. `string.Format("<a href=\"~\{0}\">{1}<a/>", routePath, linkText)` will simply render the tilde verbatim; it won't substitute the virtual directory.

Comment: you're right the ~ doesn't work as I intended. However, I still think extension method is the way to go for the DRYest solution.